# next element is (current+1) or 0 (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I have an interval let's say (0..3) where next element is +1 unless the last. Then the next is 0. I solved it by the code below. Just wondering if there is anything else outhere :-)

```
def next(max,current)

if current+1 == max
  return 0
else
  return current+1
end  
end
```

### EDIT

please note that when the code runs I need to be able to assign any 'valid number' in my example 0..3 at any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7 has Enumerable#cycle

```
(0..3).cycle{|x| puts x}
```

will cycle forever.

I think this is really cool:

```
looper = (0..3).cycle
20.times { puts looper.next }
```

Comment: It’s a method of `Enumerable`, actually, so `.to_a` is not needed.

Comment: sometimes I need to start with value different to 0. But `looper = (0..3).cycle` is still what I want to cycle. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
def next(max,current)
(current+1) % max
end
```

Should work unless `max==0`, but you could easily catch that and bail. :)

Happy coding!

Edit: You should also be aware that `next` is a reserved keyword (see [this overview](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#3)), it'd be wise to choose another name for your method..

Comment: hehe, you got there before me :P